# View API thumbnail size

Tags: box-api

Currently in the Box View API docs it says that the maximum resolution that `/documents/{id}/thumbnail` can provide is 768p.

I was wondering if it was somehow possible to convert documents into 4k images, or at the very least 1080p.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've figured it out :)

```
non_svg: For supporting users with browsers that don’t support SVG, a second
image-based conversion can be created. To request this second conversion,
include the non_svg parameter on upload. The viewer will automatically load the
correct version based on the user’s browser.
```

it's perfect for my use case, now I don't know what the resolution's going to be (I haven't tried it yet, just found this thing in the docs), but it's exactly what I wanted - to be able to convert any document to a collection of easily printable images